# iPhone 5 connected to Mac, Develop menu option says "Use for development" for device

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, ios7, developer-tools

I've used Safari's developer tools for iOS before and haven't had any problems.  In the "Develop" dropdown, it shows the device, and then the website that safari is on.  This is how it currently works for my iPhone 4s.

I'm trying to test on an iphone 5 now, and the device shows up in the Develop menu, but the nested dropdown says "Use for Development".  I've tried clicking it and nothing happens.

Has anyone run into this problem before?  I've tested in Safari 7.0 and the Nightly Build, and same thing on both.

Answer (score 5):

iOS 7 and Safari Inspector are treated very differently than I was used to.  You have to click "Trust this computer" on your phone, and use Xcode (Window menu > Organizer > Devices) to find it and click the button "Use for Development".  One problem is you need to belong to a Developer Program in order to use it.

Comment: + 1 for answering your own question.:)

Comment: Exactly what does it mean that I need to belong to a developer program? Where must I be logged in with an Apple ID connected to an active developer subscription? On the iOS device? On the Mac? On both? Where should I log in? In iCloud? In iTunes? Because it is not the same thing to log in to iCloud as to the iTunes Store, is it? Obviously, if I only had one private Apple ID with a subscription, I would simply log in with it everywhere, but in this case, I believe my employer has a subscription, but I am generally logged in with a private Apple ID.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable Web Inspector in Safari of the device you want to test (Settings -> Safari -> Advanced).

[image]

No developer subscription or whatsoever is needed.

Answer (score 1):

When your phone asks you if you want to trust the computer that you are connected to you have to click Trust in order for the Safari Inspection to work. I think this just has to do with saying that you are okay with the computer pulling data in from your phone.